# How to specify project path inside of gitlab runner build path?

Tags: git, gitlab-ci-runner

I has registered new gitlab runner.

When I deploy project using it, runner clone project by defaults into path `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/s3Cnc4se/0/zubroid/lbc/sa-parser` because project in gitlab in `zubroid/lbc/sa-parser`.

I need project will be cloned into `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/s3Cnc4se/0/sa-parser-copy-1` path. How I can do it?

**UPD**

I has tried to override `CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE` in `.gitlab-ci.yml`. but it has no effect:

```
stages:
    - deploy

production-copy:
    stage: deploy
    variables:
      CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE: 'sa-parser-copy-1'
    script:
        - echo $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE
        - docker-compose up -d --build
        - sleep 60
        - docker-compose ps
        - docker-compose logs --tail=1000
    when: manual
    tags:
        - production-copy
```

Answer (score 0):

It helped (a little bit ugly but works):

```
production-copy:
    stage: deploy
    variables:
      PROJECT_PREFIX: "copy-1-"
    script:
        - if [ ! -d "${PROJECT_PREFIX}${CI_PROJECT_NAME}" ]; then cd .. && mv ${CI_PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_PREFIX}${CI_PROJECT_NAME} && mkdir ${CI_PROJECT_NAME} && mv ${PROJECT_PREFIX}${CI_PROJECT_NAME} ${CI_PROJECT_NAME} && cd ${CI_PROJECT_NAME} ; fi
        - cd ${PROJECT_PREFIX}${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
        - docker-compose up -d --build
        - sleep 10
        - docker-compose ps
        - docker-compose logs --tail=1000
    when: manual
    tags:
        - production-copy
```